# How to find the largest and smallest element in C using arguments and array?

Tags: c, arrays

Please help how do I fix this my program...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int iics, char*argv[]){
int a,n,sum=0,average=0,highest=0,lowest=0,num[100];

for (a=1;a<iics;++a)
sum= sum + atoi (argv[a]);
printf ("The sum is %.2d \n", sum);
average=sum/a;
printf ("The average is %.2d \n", average);

highest=num[0];
lowest=num[0];
for (a=1;a<num[100];++a){
    if (num[a]>highest)
    highest=num[a];
    if(num[a]<lowest)
    lowest=num[a];}
    printf ("The highest element is %.2d \n",highest);
    printf ("The lowest element is %.2d \n", lowest);

return 0;

}
```

I got the sum and average correct but how about the highest and lowest?

Comment: Please post code, the smallest possible amount that still shows the problem. Pictures of code is not the desired format.

Comment: Is this homework? (Assuming that it is because your file name is Exf#, and because of the question)

Comment: You use an uninitialized `num`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int iics, char*argv[]){
    int a,n=0,sum=0,average,highest,lowest,num[100];

    for (a=1; a<iics; ++a)
        sum = sum + (num[n++] = atoi(argv[a]));
    printf ("The sum is %.2d \n", sum);
    average = sum / n;
    printf ("The average is %.2d \n", average);

    highest = num[0];
    lowest = num[0];
    for (a = 1; a < n; ++a){
        if(num[a] > highest)
            highest = num[a];
        if(num[a] < lowest)
            lowest = num[a];
    }
    printf ("The highest element is %.2d \n",highest);
    printf ("The lowest element is %.2d \n", lowest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works, thank you very much. I will study this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using uninitialized array `num`. So do like this

```
int i=0;
for (a=1;a<iics;++a)
{
sum= sum + atoi (argv[a]);
num[i++]=atoi9argv[a]);// just for an idea. Take care about i value

}
```

TRY by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You want to enumerate from `1` to `iics-1` like your other loops, instead you are enumerating from `1` to `num[a]-1`

change:

```
for (a=1;a<num[100];++a){
```

to:

```
for (a=1;a<iics;a++){
```

And in your earlier loop assign `atoi (argv[a])` to `num[a]`. Then these will need to start at `num[1]`:

```
highest=num[1];
lowest=num[1];
```